# Adding more detailed tick marks to x axes in density plot in R

Tags: r, axes, density-plot

This problem was solved using this coding.

Using the package lattice:

> xticks=c(0.0, 0.043, 0.052, 0.173, 0.178, 0.200, 0.360, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
>
> yticks=c(0, 5, 10, 15)
>
> densityplot(~Wart,group=Species, data=datum, xlab="Wart to spot ratio", ylab="Frequency", scales=list(x=list(at=xticks), y=list(at=yticks)))

Comment: `axis` is a base graphics function and `densityplot` is from the lattice package which are grid graphics, and generally you cannot mix the two without some work. So stick to base `plot`/`density`/`lines`/`axis` or use lattice `densityplot` with `scales` arg: `densityplot(~Wart,group=Species, data=datum, xlab="Wart to spot ratio", ylab="Frequency", scales = list(at = ticks))` or something similar

Comment: In this case, the scale I choose alters x and y.
>scale=list(x="free", y="free", at=ticks) 
This code should allow the axes to be separate from one another but they are not. I have expanded the range of y
<ylim=range(0,15)
But this hasn't brought back my original y axes which is needed. Do I need to create a different set of ticks=c() for the y axes?

Comment: I don't use lattice, so I just looked thru the man pages quickly. It would be easier to help if you posted the data you're using

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some reason why you need lattice, you can make density plots also with the base graphics, and then `axis()` will work:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
plot(density(x))
axis(side=1, at=c(-1, 1))
```

**Update:**

Here's with three distributions:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000, -1)
z <- rnorm(1000, 1)

plot(density(x), xlim=range(x, y, z))
axis(side=1, at=c(-1, 1))

lines(density(y), col="red")
lines(density(z), col="blue")
```

Comment: I am using lattice because I am looking at three groups with three different distributions of data. I need them all on the same graph separated out by a group. Would putting all different groups as x1, x2, x3 and then plotting them on top of each other work using this function?